# Write to a Text File and Copy File to Desktop from Phone's File System

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I've made a mobile puzzle-like game that has some simple levels loaded from a text file line by line.

Now I am trying to make an editor in the game so when I draw a level from the editor, text file will be updated with the new line.

My Start() function looks like this:

```
void Start()
    {
        TextAsset file = Resources.Load("levels") as TextAsset; 
        //text.text = file.text;
        levels = new List<string[]>();
        string[] linesFromfile = file.text.Split("\n"[0]);
        currentLevel = System.Convert.ToInt32(linesFromfile[0]);
        for(int i = 1; i < linesFromfile.Length; i++){
            levels.Add(linesFromfile[i].Split(';'));
        }
        loadLevel(currentLevel);
    }
```

And my text file:

```
1
Side00-01,1;Side01-11,1;Side10-11,2;Side00-10,1;Side10-20,1
```

In the first line of file I try to save the level number that player last played. Other lines represent each level. "Side00-01" part is the name of the side and the number next to it shows the color of the side. Maybe a dumb way to do this but it looked simple to me. loadLevel() function gets called after completing each level.

1) I've read many tutorials etc. and afaik we can't  simply write to a file in Android as simple as reading it like above, right? How should I do the writing part?

2) And another problem is I should send this editor part to some level designer friend and then I should get back the levels he drew. If we can't get the file from the file system of the phone how can I accomplish such thing?

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-) You should write and read your files from `Application.persistentDataPath, so you can store them cross platform.

2-) Create a button, which generates a `UnityWebRequest`. Read your friend's local file on Application.persistentDataPath with System.IO class then send all string as a post web request to your server. I think this part needs some server-side experience.

Comment: So should I use Application.persistentDataPath instead of Resources.load while reading too?

I don't have any server-side experience or even multiplayer experience, so if there is an easier way that would be better but I think I have to try this.

Thanks!

Comment: Your comment gave me an idea such that I will save the levels in a string and then instead of writing to a file, i will send it to me via email.

Comment: Sure it will help too. But when I read your scenario, I think you will need some kind of web services in near future :)

Comment: Yeah that would be a better approach of course but as a beginner, my solution works good enough for me :)